# how to check type in typescript. instance of not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to convert a simple custom Link component in React to use TypeScript.

Here is the simple Link component in JavaScript:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

const StyledLink = styled(RouterLink)`
  color: blue;
`;

const StyledAnchor = styled.a`
  color: red;
`;

export default function Link(props) {
  return Boolean(props.to) ? (
    <StyledLink {...props} />
  ) : (
    <StyledAnchor {...props} />
  );
}
```

And here is usage of the above component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'components/Link'

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <>
      <Link href="https://stackoverflow.com">external link</Link>
      <br />
      <Link to="/">internal link</Link>
    </>
  )
}
```

But I'm having problems converting the above Link component to use TypeScript.

Here is what I have so far in TypeScript:

```
import { AnchorHTMLAttributes } from 'react'
import { Link as RouterLink, LinkProps } from 'react-router-dom'
import styled, { StyledComponent } from '@emotion/styled'
import { EmotionJSX } from '@emotion/react/types/jsx-namespace'

type AnchorProps = AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>

const StyledLink: StyledComponent<LinkProps> = styled(RouterLink)`
  color: blue;
`

const StyledAnchor: StyledComponent<AnchorProps> = styled.a`
  color: red;
`

export default function Link(
  props: LinkProps | AnchorProps
): EmotionJSX.Element {
  if (/* HOW TO CHECK IF props IS LinkProps or AnchorProps */) {
    return <StyledLink {...props} />
  } else {
    return <StyledAnchor {...props} />
  }
}
```

So how can I find out whether `props` is of type `LinkProps` or `AnchorProps` in Typescript?
I already tried `instanceof` but I get an error `'LinkProps' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`:

```
export default function Link(
  props: LinkProps | AnchorProps
): EmotionJSX.Element {
  if (props instanceof LinkProps) {
    return <StyledLink {...props} />
  } else {
    return <StyledAnchor {...props} />
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript won't allow you to directly do an `instanceof` check, but there's a trick you can use to get what you want. `LinkProps` is an interface that requires certain fields to be present, and `AnchorProps` requires different fields. So if you check for the presence of, say, `to` (a field that only exists on `LinkProps`), then TypeScript will know that if the check succeeds then `props` is a `LinkProps` and if it fails then `props` is an `AnchorProps`.

So for your example, you could write:

```
export default function Link(
  props: LinkProps | AnchorProps
): EmotionJSX.Element {
  if ('to' in props) {
    return <StyledLink {...props} />
  } else {
    return <StyledAnchor {...props} />
  }
}
```